# It doesn't work to upload a video to youtube with Google API V3 with Web JSON in a ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, google-api

I have bellow follow code inspired from sample youtube google api upload video.

I generated Web JSON for my domain, when i run this code i write with Debug.Write in log file but i see in log wrote only "Inside Run" doesn't pass after AuthorizeAsync method and neither error received, do you have any idea why doesn't works ?

In console application with native JSON generated works ok.

My web application is ASP.NET Web Forms.

```
public async Task Run()
{
    Debug.Write("Inside Run");
    UserCredential credential = null;

    try
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(ClientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        //File.AppendAllText("exceptie.txt", ex.Message);
    }
    Debug.Write("After Authentification");

    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });            

    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = TitleVideo;
    video.Snippet.Description = Description;
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
    var filePath1 = FilePath; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath1, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        videosInsertRequest.Upload();
    }
}

void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
        case UploadStatus.Uploading:
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
            lbl.Text += "<br> " + string.Format("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
            break;

        case UploadStatus.Failed:
            Debug.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
            lbl.Text += "<br> " + string.Format("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
            break;
    }
}

void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    lbl.Text += "<br> " + string.Format("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
}
```